# KivyMD how to get and change text from KivyMD textfield

Tags: python, kivy

```
class MainWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        gang = ObjectProperty(None)

        gang.text = 'Button'
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)      
        
        
Test().run()
```

And the KV code

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    gang:gang
    MDFillRoundFlatButton
        
        text:"Validate"
        size_hint:0.3, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top':0.2}
    MDTextFieldRound
        id:gang
        hint_text:"Enter Your License Key"
        multiline:False
        size_hint: (0.7, None)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        halign:"center"
<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    on_enter:app.file_manager_open()
```

Whenever i run this i get the output ' AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'text' ' I'm guessing somehow the object property isn't syncing up, i apologize that the code is super messed up.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a `Property` in a class, it must be outside any methods. Try changing:

```
class MainWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        gang = ObjectProperty(None)

        gang.text = 'Button'
```

to:

```
class MainWindow(Screen):
    gang = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        self.gang.text = 'Button'
```

This defines the `ObjectProperty` correctly, and delays the setting of the `text` property until the `ObjectProperty` is set.

Comment: this works however for some reason i can't call the function from my kivy code, it says it can't find the MainWindow class

Comment: What function are you trying to call?

Comment: I'm trying to call the on_kv_post from my kivy code, when i do that it says it can't find the mainwindow class

Comment: You don't call the `on_kv_post()` method, kivy will call it for you after the `kv` rules are done. Have a look at the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget).